# How to filter methods with java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I want to get all methods from a class but exclude the inherited methods such as : wait, toString, hash etc.

Is there a built in way to do it or do I need to define a blacklist and check the method name against it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ignore methods like

```
for(Method method: clazz.getMethods()) {
    if(method.getDeclaringClass() == Object.class) continue;

}
```

Note: this will include methods overridden in a sub-class.

If you don't want any inherited methods you can use

```
for(Method method: clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `MyClass.getDeclaredMethods()`

Answer (score 0):

clazz.getDeclaredMethods() will deliver methods defined by current class (and thus effectively exclude inherited ones). However, typical pattern is to walk up class hierarchy 
and exlucde those  coming from  Object

Answer (score 0):

You can use [collection commons](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) for this.

You will just have to declare w predicate and then use the:

```
CollectionUtils.filter(collection, predicate);
```

Where collection is the bag of methods.
Predicate is the logical function that accept the element on the list